# Deletiion of multiple PS files using JCL - Mainframe

Tags: jcl

I have the requirement to delete the below datasets at one go.

TEST.D210101.FILE ,
TEST.D210102.FILE.

i have written the IDCAMS but is not working if I have given in the below way.

**DELETE (TEST.D**.*) FORCE**

Its working only if I have second qualifier.

**DELETE (TEST.D210101.*) FORCE**

Could you please let us know how to solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Delete TEST.D*.FILE
```

For idcams delete you can only use **1 *** . For more complex deletes use the Data Facility (DF*) utilities, [see](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.2.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r2.adru000/delds.htm)

---

Also Google is your friend, try googling `idcams wild cards delete`